# Are same domain iframes faster than cross domain?

Tags: javascript, performance, iframe

I'm in a position where I can choose whether or not to host the content of my iframes on the same domain or on other domains. Are there any benefits of hosting them on the same domain, like speed?

I am asking this because I found an article saying that CORS is slower than having the resource on the same domain (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-terrible-performance-cost-of-cors-api-on-the-single-page-application-spa-6fcf71e50147/)

Is this the case for iframes too?

Comment: CORS requires extra requests, iframes have nothing to do with that

Comment: I only briefly checked, but it appears the article mainly makes its point due to the necessecity of pre-flight requests in many cases. That is not a thing for iframes to begin with. If anything, the amount of cookies send with every request could be an argument for different domains when it comes to iframes. But all in all, this is most likely one of those cases where the answer simply is, _it doesn’t matter_ - making this a typical _premature optimization_ question.

Comment: Thanks! Juan Mendes, CBroe

Comment: @CBroe, You could copy-paste your answer as an answer such that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an article saying that CORS is slower than having the resource on the same domain

I only briefly checked, but it appears the article mainly makes its point due to the necessecity of *pre-flight requests* in many cases. That is not a thing for iframes to begin with.

If anything, the amount of cookies send with every request could be an argument for different domains when it comes to iframes.